# failed: Network error while downloading Excel file generated by jupyter notebook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

my jupyter notebook is saving a dataframe(having styles) to an excel file. then I have created a link to download this excel file:

```
df=df.to_excel('ABC.xlsx', index=True)
filename ='ABC.xlsx'
file_link = "<a href='{href}' download='ABC.xlsx'> Download ABC.xlsx</a>"
html = HTML(file_link.format(href=filename))
dispaly(html)
```

but when i click on link-Download ABC.xlsx, I am getting- *Failed: Network error*.
On the contrary it is working fine when i am downloading *CSV file* the same way

Adding csv code, there is some base64 encoding added in csv code without which csv code is also not working:

```
def func(df,title="Download csv file",filename="ABC.csv"):
    csv=df.to_csv(index=True) 
    b64 =base64.b64encode(csv.encode()) 
    payload=b64.decode()
   html = "<a href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" download="{filename}" target="_blank">{title}</a>"
   html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
   return HTML(html)
```

i tried editing this function for excel file:

```
def func(df,title="Download excel file",filename="ABC.xlsx"):
    xls=df.to_excel("xyz.xlsx",index=True) 
    b64 =base64.b64encode(xls.encode()) 
    payload=b64.decode()
   html = "<a href="data:text/xls;base64,{payload}" download="{filename}" target="_blank">{title}</a>"
   html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
   return HTML(html)
```

for excel code it giving error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: can you also paste the working csv way?

Comment: i have added csv code above. thanks

Comment: but there are some differences, such as `filename`, `target="_blank`

Comment: yes i tried the exact code for excel too, by just writing xlsx intead of csv. let me give that code too

Comment: i have corrected the csv code, without encoding none of them is working. pls suggest

Comment: now you still hardcoded xlxs filename(xyz.xlsx), is it typo?

Comment: no i have provided it intentionally, bcz it was giving error to provide required positional argument excel_writer and since i need to write only one sheet/object so i gave the file name

Comment: then why `filename="ABC.xlsx"` in xlsx part?

Comment: that is default parameter

Comment: but you passed the parameter to link url, which you finally click(and you don't write to)

Comment: if i am getting you correct, i am passing filename to download attribute, which is just for reference purpose, it can be any value; when the user downloads the file it will get downloaded with this filename

Comment: i just realized you used return value of `to_csv` and `to_excel`, `to_csv` only return the content **when you don't specify filename**, and `to_excel` **don't return anything** at all(if i understand doc correctly). so i think you need read the file again and convert to base64. if needed i can make an answer.

Comment: while  calling the func i am passing a file name which user desires

Comment: sorry i am not getting you, which file i need to read again

Comment: i posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you csv code, you use `csv=df.to_csv(index=True)`, according to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

> If path_or_buf is None, returns the resulting csv format as a string.
> Otherwise returns None.

here you didn't specify `path_or_buf`, so return value is csv **content**. this is why you can download csv.

Now `to_excel` [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) desn't say it has any return value. so your payload don't contain anything at all.

To solve, you can manually open file again and read as base64 format string:

```
def file_to_base64(file):
#file should be the actual file name you wrote
    with open(file, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        return encoded_string.decode()
```

replace the two lines

```
b64 =base64.b64encode(xls.encode()) 
payload=b64.decode()
```

with:

```
payload = file_to_base64(file)
```

Comment: styles should also come along with data in excel file, correct me if i am wrong. Seems need to work more to import styles along with the data

Comment: what is 'styles', is it xlsx related or html related? the above code just read everything as bytes, it not only read plain text.

Comment: actually i have added styles to my dataframe, like background colour border etc, for that i wanted to download it in form of excel file

Comment: where did you add styles? please paste the code

Comment: i am writing few styles for example- `df=df.style.format({'A':"{:.0f}%", "B":"{:.0f}%" , na_rep=' ').set_table_styles([{'selector':'th','props':[('font-size','8pt'),('border','1px solid black')]}])`   here A, B are columns

Comment: so here in styles i am rounding the decimal values, adding % symbol to values etc.

Comment: i'm not familiar with dataframe styles, and i think it's totally another question: 'how to export dataframe to excel with customized styles'